# How to solve create react app directories error?

Tags: npm, create-react-app

I have installed react js and run the basics commands on CMD but it's saying and repeating the same every time as a screenshot. I also installed it globally, got node,npm, and created react app version. But when I `create-react-app tutorial` it's saying an error

```
C:\Users\ehsan>node -v
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\ehsan>node -v
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\ehsan>node -v
v16.16.0

C:\Users\ehsan>npm -v
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
8.11.0

C:\Users\ehsan>npm install -g create-react-app
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

changed 67 packages, and audited 68 packages in 5s

4 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

2 high severity vulnerabilities

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.

C:\Users\ehsan>mkdir tut
Access is denied.

C:\Users\ehsan>create-react-app --version
5.0.1

C:\Users\ehsan>create-react-app tut
node:fs:1349
  handleErrorFromBinding(ctx);
  ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'tut'
    at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1349:3)
    at Object.module.exports.makeDirSync (C:\Users\ehsan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\make-dir.js:23:13)
    at createApp (C:\Users\ehsan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:257:6)
    at C:\Users\ehsan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:223:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  errno: -4048,
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  code: 'EPERM',
  path: 'tut'
}

C:\Users\ehsan>create-react-app --version
5.0.1

C:\Users\ehsan>mkdir tut
Access is denied.

C:\Users\ehsan>mkdir -tut
Access is denied.

C:\Users\ehsan>create-react-app tutu
node:fs:1349
  handleErrorFromBinding(ctx);
  ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'tutu'
    at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1349:3)
    at Object.module.exports.makeDirSync (C:\Users\ehsan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\make-dir.js:23:13)
    at createApp (C:\Users\ehsan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:257:6)
    at C:\Users\ehsan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:223:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  errno: -4048,
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  code: 'EPERM',
  path: 'tutu'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check your node installation, looks like it is either not installed or node has not been added to your environment path variable.

When that is solved running `node --version` in your terminal would verify.

After you can use

```
npx create-react-app@latest your_app_name
```

to create a react app in your desired directory